# Parse Complex Json Data with VB.net and Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, json.net

I'm building a windows application using vb.net to take a Json file that will be downloaded daily and parse it and enter the values into a SQL database. The only part I'm getting stuck on is being about to parse the Json data to get the values I need.

```
Public Sub json_parse(ByVal result_json As String)
        Try
            Dim json As String = result_json
            Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
            Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
            For Each item As JProperty In data
                item.CreateReader()
                Select Case item.Name
                    Case "data"
                        For Each msg As JObject In item.Values
                            MsgBox(msg.ToString)
                        Next
                End Select
            Next
        Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
            'MsgBox(__unusedException1__.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "wsj_mdstrip_na,us": {
      "set": 1562756496071,
      "ttl": 300000,
      "data": {
        "id": "na,us",
        "type": "wsj_mdstrip",
        "data": [
          {
            "timeZone": "CDT",
            "localTimeZoneTimestamp": "5:51 AM CDT 07/10/19",
            "localTimestamp": "5:51 AM 07/10/19",
            "etTimestamp": "6:51 AM ET 07/10/19",
            "mdTimestamp": "2019-07-10T06:51:35-04:00",
            "timestamp": "2019-07-10T05:51:35.365",
            "chartingSymbol": "Future/US/XCBT/YM00",
            "updatedTimestamp": "2019-07-10T07:01:36-04:00"
          },
          {
            "deltaBarPosNeg": "deltaBar-neg",
            "etTimestamp": "6:51 AM ET 07/10/19",
            "chartingSymbol": "Future/US/XCME/ES00",
            "pastCloses": [
              {
                "range": "P1Y",
                "price": 2775.75
              },
              {
                "range": "P3Y",
                "price": 2145.75
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "wsj_nav_na,us": {
      "set": 1562754843231,
      "ttl": 1800000,
      "isStale": false
    },
    "mdc_cashprices_": {
      "set": 1562756402351,
      "ttl": 90000,
      "data": {
        "id": "{\"requestedCommodities\":\"all\",\"groupIntoMapBy\":\"type\",\"groupIntoSetsBy\":\"subType\"}",
        "type": "mdc_cashprices",
        "data": {
          "instruments": [
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "Gold-EnglehardFab",
              "instrumentID": "511498",
              "name": "Engelhard fabricated products",
              "subType": "Gold, per troy oz",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "1500.72",
              "previousDay": "1509.33",
              "previousYear": "1351.58"
            },
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "Silver-EngelhrdFab",
              "instrumentID": "511558",
              "name": "Engelhard fabricated products",
              "subType": "Silver, troy oz.",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "18.0600",
              "previousDay": "18.0960",
              "previousYear": "19.3200"
            },
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "SilverHandy&HarmB",
              "instrumentID": "511560",
              "name": "Handy & Harman base price",
              "subType": "Silver, troy oz.",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "15.1070",
              "previousDay": "15.0420",
              "previousYear": "16.1000"
            },
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "Platinum-EngelhFab",
              "instrumentID": "511554",
              "name": "Platinum, Engelhard fabricated products",
              "subType": "Other precious metals",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "912.0",
              "previousDay": "914.0",
              "previousYear": "946.0"
            },
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "Palladium-EngelInd",
              "instrumentID": "511553",
              "name": "Palladium, Engelhard industrial bullion",
              "subType": "Other precious metals",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "1561.0",
              "previousDay": "1573.0",
              "previousYear": "955.0"
            },
            {
              "code": null,
              "djShortName": "Palladium-EngelFab",
              "instrumentID": "511552",
              "name": "Palladium, Engelhard fabricated products",
              "subType": "Other precious metals",
              "type": "Precious metals",
              "ask": "-",
              "bid": "-",
              "last": "1661.0",
              "previousDay": "1673.0",
              "previousYear": "1055.0"
            }
          ],
          "timestamp": "7/09/19"
        }
      }
    },
    "consumer_corphat_corphat": {
      "set": 1562756495973,
      "ttl": 90000,
      "data": {
        "id": "corphat",
        "type": "consumer_corphat",
        "data": [
          {
            "ncLinks": [
              {
                "title": "Big Decisions",
                "url": "http://www.bigdecisions.com/",
                "nofollow": "false"
              },
              {
                "title": "Business Spectator",
                "url": "https://www.businessspectator.com.au/",
                "nofollow": "false"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "djLinks": [
              {
                "title": "Barron's",
                "url": "https://www.barrons.com",
                "nofollow": "false"
              },
              {
                "title": "BigCharts",
                "url": "http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com",
                "nofollow": "false"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "isStale": false
    }
  },
  "currentState": {
    "data": [
      "0.0.3.0.0",
      "0.0.3.1.0.0.2"
    ],
    "components": {
      "code___decoratedComponent___275181c7-8620-4df3-a008-d0cd9937db22___WSJTheme---WSJBase---WSJForms---WSJTables": {
        "id": "275181c7-8620-4df3-a008-d0cd9937db22",
        "decorators": [
          "WSJTheme",
          "WSJBase",
          "WSJForms",
          "WSJTables"
        ]
      },
      "code___decoratedComponent___c8882c9c-15d3-4d1f-9b0e-81b6f321365d___WSJTheme---WSJBase---WSJForms---WSJTables": {
        "id": "c8882c9c-15d3-4d1f-9b0e-81b6f321365d",
        "decorators": [
          "WSJTheme",
          "WSJBase",
          "WSJForms",
          "WSJTables"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the values for "last", "previousDay" and "previousYear" from:

data  >  mdc_cashprices_  >  data  >  instruments  >  (where djShortName = "Gold-EnglehardFab" and djShortName = "Silver-EngelhrdFab" and djShortName = "Platinum-EngelhFab" and djShortName = "Palladium-EngelFab")

I'm also trying to get the value for "timestamp" from:

data  >  mdc_cashprices_  >  data  > timestamp

In my current code I can only get to the 1st "data" tier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to view it more easily.

Then simply

```
Dim Something as JObject = JObject.Parse(<your JSON>)
```

Then get what you want with

```
Something1 = Something("data")("mdc_cashprices")("data")("data")("instruments")(0)("last") 'basically you just traverse the levels, you use the id/text for regular stuff (inside {}) and numbers for arrays (inside [])
```

Since it's an array you would probably want to loop it

```
For Each item In Something("data")("mdc_cashprices")("data")("data")("instruments")
        Something2 = item("last")
Next
```

Btw there are some formatting issues here >>> mdc_cashprices_{\"req... <<< that _ and \ shouldn't be there"

Comment: Thank You for your help with the 1st part. Maybe you could help me with my 2nd part too.

I'm trying to get the value of: data > mdc_cashprices_ > data > data > timestamp
By using this code:

    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(result_json)
            For Each item In ser("data")("mdc_cashprices_")("data")("data")
                Dim timestamp As String = item("timestamp")
                gatheredData = timestamp
            Next

But i keep getting this error: "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."

Comment: Put a breakpoint at timestap and see if item is something. if it is inspect it and see where is the timestamp located, also please edit the json in the question with the corrected one.

Comment: "item" contained: "timestamp": "7/09/19", so it looks like I'm good to go. Thank You for all your help!